# Elementary introduction to (quantum) hall effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, quantum-hall-effect

Where can I find an elementary introduction to classical and [quantum hall effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Hall_effect)?
Only physics I know is some basic quantum mechanics, EM and statistical physics. My goal eventually is to understand FQHE in a field theoretic context.

Answer (score 2):

These [lectures on the QHE and FQHE](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9907002) given at the Les Houches summer school are a great start imho.